# using XmlDocument instead of XElement

Tags: javascript

using XmlDocument instead of XElement

Comment: You don't have a standard xml file. Standard XML has only one root tag.  You have two root tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what made you to pick `XmlDocument` over `Linq` to `Xml`. Given a choice I prefer using `XDocument` to work with `Xml`.

Anyways, you could do this with `XmlDocument`.

```
public static string Stringify(XmlDocument doc)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result.Append("ID=");

    foreach(XmlElement element in doc.GetElementsByTagName("var_name")) 
    {
        result.Append(element.GetAttribute("name"));

        foreach(XmlElement child in element.ChildNodes)
        {
            result.Append(string.Format(" {0}={1}", child.GetAttribute("ns"), child.GetAttribute("ps")));
        }
    }


    return result.ToString();
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
ID=name1 Desc=0 otp=0
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FBDicx)

Comment: Thanks man. But i am getting an error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." in this code part in the main method                                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"D:\new/sample.xml");

Comment: Use `doc.Load(@"D:\new/sample.xml");` which loads from file,

Comment: Actually i am trying to use LoadXml instead of Load since i will be loading the xml dynamically from a string instead of placing the xml locally. This is one reason where i moved from Xelement to XmlDocument

Comment: @stackdoubt in which case, just use `XDocument.Parse` or `XElement.Parse` which parses a `string`.  There really shouldn't be many reasons to pick `XmlDocument` - it's an old and unfriendly API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

Usings

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "p")]
public class P
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns")]
    public string Ns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ps")]
    public string Ps { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "var_name")]
public class Var_name
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "p")]
    public List<P> P { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "msg")]
public class Msg
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "var_name")]
    public Var_name Var_name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Code

```
try
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("xml.xml");

    string XML = xmlDoc.InnerXml.ToString();
    byte[] BUFXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML);
    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(BUFXML);

    XmlSerializer DeserializerPlaces = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Msg));
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
    {
        Msg dezerializedXML = (Msg)DeserializerPlaces.Deserialize(reader);

    }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over dezerializedXML and you should have you values
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    throw;
}
    }
}
```

That code will take your xml (read in from a file called xml.xml in the same folder as you application *.exe) then it will de serialise it to an object called 'dezerializedXML'.....